# Can this one specific case be generalized?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, determinant, analytic-functions

So just to start I am not aware if this can be generalized or if it is just a weird occurrence. But I was doing by problem set for linear algebra and I had to compute the Wronskian determinant of the following functions. 
$$ f_1(x)= e^x, \quad f_2(x)=xe^x, \quad f_3(x) = x^2e^x $$ 
so I got the matrix: 
$$ W= \begin{bmatrix}
e^x& xe^x& x^2e^x \\
e^x& e^x+xe^x&  2xe^x+x^2e^x \\
e^x& 2e^x+xe^x&  2e^x+4xe^x+x^2e^x \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

and what I noticed is that if if take an $e^x$ out of W and call the new matrix W' we get:
$$ W'= e^x\begin{bmatrix}
1& x& x^2 \\
1& 1+x&  2x+x^2 \\
1& 2+x&  2+4x+x^2 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Now I noticed that $det(W)=e^{3x}det(W')$ and I was wondering that could this be generalized to all functions such that say we have again a 3x3 matrix, say $M$ and we have a common factor that is the analytic function say $f(x)$ then if we take $f(x)$ out of $M$, like you can for a constant, to get a new matrix $M'$ then would the same situation appear such that $det(M)=[f(x)]^3 det(M')$ ? In my example $f(x) = e^x$, so can this be true for any analytic function ?

Comment: If you have a factor that is in every element of any row you can "factor it out."  You can also do it if it is common to every element in a column.  In this case you $e^x$ shows in all 3 rows.  So you can factor it out 3 times.

Comment: You can write $W = f(x) I_3\  W' \implies \det(W) = \det(f(x)I_3)\det(W') = f(x)^3 \det(W') $ (where $I_3$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this property can be generalized even more so than you specify. You can take ANY size NxN matrix and factor out ANY function f(x). You don't need a "common factor" since you can always pull out f(x) from g(x) as follows: g(x)=f(x)*[ g(x)/f(x) ]

So for a NxN matrix, M, with entries Mij at the ith row and jth column

det(M)=[f(x)]^N*det(M′) where the entries of matrix, M' are M'ij=Mij/f(x)

This is because multiplying the row of a matrix by a constant,K, multiplies the determinant by K. So dividing out f(x) from all N rows would multiply the determinant by 1/(f(x))^N

Comment: Hi, use latex (click on edit under the questions)